# JQuery.Form.JS XHR error in IE9

Tags: jquery, forms, internet-explorer-9

I am having a problem with using `jQuery.form.js` in IE 9, where XHR is returning the DOM of the `<form>`, instead of the response from the `POST`.

I have created a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hu5fb8z0/8/) to demonstrate the problem, which is based on [this](http://malsup.com/jquery/form/progress.html) (which does work in IE9).

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="http://malsup.github.com/jquery.form.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="http://jquery.malsup.com/form/file-echo2.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <input type="file" name="myfile">
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>     
    <div id="status"></div>
    <script>
        (function() {
            var status = $('#status');
            $('form').ajaxForm({
                //xhrFields: {withCredentials: true},
                beforeSend: function() {
                    status.html("Submitting...");
                },
                success: function() {
                    status.html("Done...");
                },
                complete: function(xhr) {
                    status.html(xhr.responseText);
                }
            }); 
        })();       
    </script>
</body>
```

Given the original example works in IE 9, I would think my jsfiddle should work, but I just can't figure it out.  Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

After a night sleep and with a clearer mind, and I can now answer my own question!!

First, I turned on debugging by adding:

```
$.fn.ajaxSubmit.debug = true;
```

With debugging, I can see the following in the console.

```
[jquery.form] fileAPI :false
[jquery.form] state = loading
[jquery.form] cannot get iframe.contentWindow document: TypeError: Permission denied
[jquery.form] cannot get iframe.contentDocument: Error: Access is denied.
```

Hence, the problem is due to CORS, where the response from the `POST` request is loaded into the temporary `<iframe>`, but the parent `<html>` is unable to access the `<iframe>`.

As far as I can tell, there is no way to do a CORS request in IE9 using the jquery.form.js plugin.

However, if you are writing your own service hosting on the same server, the key is to return the response as HTML or XML (as explained in the official [documentation](http://malsup.com/jquery/form/#file-upload))

Here is a code snippet of how I did it with C# Web API 2:

```
public class UploadController : ApiController
{
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> UploadFile()
    {
        //
        // Verify that this is an HTML Form file upload request
        //
        if (!Request.Content.IsMimeMultipartContent("form-data"))
        {
            throw new HttpResponseException(Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.UnsupportedMediaType));
        }

        var filesReadToProvider = await Request.Content.ReadAsMultipartAsync();

        //
        // Read the file... return a string (i.e. strResp)
        // 

        var resp = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
        resp.Content = resp.Content = new StringContent(strResp, Encoding.UTF8, "text/plain");

        return resp;
    }
}
```

Then on the frontend UI, the `xhr.responseText` should now be correct and returned as string.  Use JavaScript to parse the string back in JSON or array.

Hope this is useful for anyone else facing similar problem.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with IE11 and jQuery.Form 3.51, for a form that has multiple file upload controls.  From working with older version of jQuery.Form, I knew about the text/plain or text/html content-type requirements, so I already had that in place.  That is, I was calling

```
drupal_add_http_header('Content-Type', 'text/html');
```

in my handler function.  I had read somewhere years ago that setting headers should be the first thing that you do in a handler function, so it was the very first line in the function.  Anyway, when I added some debugging code *before* that call, it started working!  So basically my solution was to make sure that the above function call was not the first line in my function.  Don't know if that is logical...